# Formatting the result of an SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the below query in order to replace '@' with '-' and is giving me the output as below.

### Query:

```
select upper(replace(replace(software_module_component_name,'DBSM:',''),'@','-')) as Test from SOFTWARE_MODULE 
where software_module_component_name like 'DBSM:PUKEIM%'
```

### Output:

```
Test
PUKEIMA1-GBL05266-ORACLE - V11.2.0.4
PUKEIMA1-GBL05267-IBM - V11.2.0.4
PUKEIMA1-GBL05268-INTEL - V11.2.0.4
```

but I would like to see the output as below.

### Requied Output:

```
Test
PUKEIMA1-GBL05266
PUKEIMA1-GBL05267
PUKEIMA1-GBL05268
```

Regards,
Bharath Vikas

Answer (score 0):

Since your output look symmetric you can use  `SUBSTR`  and fix the `SUBSTR` character.Try this:

```
 SELECT SUBSTR (
          UPPER (
             REPLACE (REPLACE (software_module_component_name, 'DBSM:', ''),
                      '@',
                      '-')),
          1,
          17)
          AS Test
  FROM SOFTWARE_MODULE
 WHERE software_module_component_name LIKE 'DBSM:PUKEIM%'
```

You can do it as :

```
WITH tbl (str)
     AS (SELECT 'PUKEIMA1-GBL05266-ORACLE - V11.2.0.4' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'PUKEIMA1-GBL05267-IBM - V11.2.0.4' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'PUKEIMA1-GBL05268-INTEL - V11.2.0.4' FROM DUAL)
--Actual query
SELECT    REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
                         '[^-]+',
                         1,
                         1)
       || REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
                         '(.*?)([^-]+)',
                         1,
                         2)
          AS
  FROM tbl
```

;

Comment: Thanks for that @XING, but is there any way of not manually entering 1,17 in the code? because I've some lines where the '-' comes at place 20 or at place 10.

Comment: @Vikas check the revised answer.